# Можно ли при помощи @DateTimeFormat сделать такое?

Tags: java, spring, datetime, аннотации

Можно ли при помощи параметра pattern к аннотации @DateTimeFormat сделать такого вида валидацию `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.sss]±hh:mm`
([.sss] - опционально от 1 до 3 цифр)? И может ли @DateTimeFormat валидировать String например?

Comment: от чего зависит опциональность миллисекунд? Что вы понимаете под валидацией - cоответствие вашей даты жтому формату?

Comment: Я думаю в таком случае лучше работать с регулярными выражениями

Comment: что означает ± в вашей формуле?

Comment: опциональность зависит от времени, под валидацией понимаю проверку на соответствие указанному формату, +- это в результате будет значить примерное значение. В конечном итоге наверное придется делать регулярным выражением, все дело в том, что в spring есть expression language, который позволяет в разных местах им оперировать, в том числе и в аннотациях, я хотел его использовать, но ни разу с ним в подобных ситуациях не встречался...

Comment: я расширил свой ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нашел ответ в английской ветке

этот метод должен вам помочь. Мы просто парсим и если вылетает ошибка то значит не соответствует.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS");

boolean isValidDate(String input) {
  try {
      format.parse(input);
      return true;
   }
   catch(ParseException e){
      return false;
   }
}
```

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149680/regex-date-format-validation-on-java)

почитайте внимательно что каждая буква означаетю разница между DD и dd

[форматирование даты](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

2. в случае с ±hh:mm можно написать метод

   Date min, max;
   Date date;

   return date.after(min) && date.before(max);

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/883060/how-can-i-determine-if-a-date-is-between-two-dates-in-java)

3. реализацию опуиональноти миллисекунд вижу только в написании трех методов тз пункта 1 которые по очереди будут проверять.